# Normal corners on select boxes - css

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

All my select boxes have rounded corners, but I want normal corners. I think the theme I am using on my Wordpress site overwrites the normal boxes.

This is the site where you see the select boxes with rounded corners! 
http://www.fernwehreisen.de/reiseanfrage/

Can somebody point me in the right direction? How do I get normal corners via `CSS`? 
I have tried changing border radius and so on, but nothing helps, because I can't find the class that manages this.
Thanks.

Comment: Post a minimal part of your html/css to show what you mean

Comment: .wpcf7 select {
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;
} This is what i try to avoid the rounded corners...but it doesn't change..it still show up the same rounded corners...

Comment: Not as a comment, and not only the css, a minimal working code that reproduce the issue

Comment: The option selects on that page look like having square corners to me...

Answer (score 1):

`border-radius` is the governing CSS name of your issue. For different browsers, it has different manifestations, and your `-webkit-border-radius` is one of them.

In addition to your current code, you can add `border-radius:0px`, this should take care of most modern browsers.

If that still doesn't work, that means probably your selector `.wpcf7 select` is overridden by your theme's other CSS rules. For blindly overcome them, you can add `!important` after the CSS rule.

```
.wpcf7 select {
-webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
border-radius:0px !important
}
```

Or you can try to refine your selector so yours override them. If you still don't understand, google `css selector` and read the first link.